# Unable to change image in an XNA game studio game

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

For a college project I have had to download an existing 2D XNA game called [Platformer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Platformer-68643e63) and changed various things in it, for example character renders, background images, and some variables (points per item pick-up, time remaining etc.).

In my game I am attempting to replace the playable character image with my own. I have changed the image in the games content folder, making sure it's the same file type and dimensions.

Swapped this image:

`Platformer > Content > Sprites > Player > Idle.png`

With this one:

`Platformer > Content > Sprites > Player > Gorilla.png`

In the player.cs file within Visual Studios there is a class called `LoadContent()` which appears to load all the player animations and sounds etc.

```
public void LoadContent()
    {
        // Load animated textures.
        idleAnimation = new Animation(Level.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Player/Gorilla"), 0.1f, true);
        runAnimation = new Animation(Level.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Player/Run"), 0.1f, true);
        jumpAnimation = new Animation(Level.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Player/Jump"), 0.1f, false);
        celebrateAnimation = new Animation(Level.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Player/Celebrate"), 0.1f, false);
        dieAnimation = new Animation(Level.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Player/Die"), 0.1f, false);

        // Calculate bounds within texture size.            
        int width = (int)(idleAnimation.FrameWidth * 0.4);
        int left = (idleAnimation.FrameWidth - width) / 2;
        int height = (int)(idleAnimation.FrameWidth * 0.8);
        int top = idleAnimation.FrameHeight - height;
        localBounds = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);

        // Load sounds.            
        killedSound = Level.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Sounds/PlayerKilled");
        jumpSound = Level.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Sounds/PlayerJump");
        fallSound = Level.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Sounds/PlayerFall");
    }
```

After changing the image in the `Sprites` folder and attempt to run the project (F5) I get the following error:

`Error loading "Sprites\Player\Gorilla". File not found.`

Referring to this line of code:

`idleAnimation = new Animation(Level.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Player/Gorilla"), 0.1f, true);`

In the `IntelliTrace` window on the right hand side I get:

`Exception Thrown: Could not find file: Platformer\bin\x86\Debug\Content\Sprites\Player\Gorilla.xnb`

So I assume I have to make a Gorilla.xnb as well as a Gorilla.png file? But how do I do this? Is it something I can do within Visual studios?

I got the projext already built and running from the website above so not sure how to add new content images to this kind of project.

Thanks

Comment: When you look at the file properties for Gorilla.png in your content project, is it set to __Compile__ as its build action?  What are its importer and processor set to?

Comment: The weird thing is i cant find any of the existing images used in the game in visual studios nor any reference to them anywhere. But when I run the game all images are there in the game working perfectly. I have added the Gorilla.png file to the Sprites folder not to the VS project anywhere

Comment: The Platformer demo includes a project called 'Content' which should be loaded into Visual Studio alongside the game.  It sounds like this project isn't being built; it's what generates the XNB files.  Make sure it's a part of your solution; it's at Content\Content.csproj.